# Laravel hasManyThrough 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have two tables as below:
users table:

```
|id|name|email|password|created_at|updated_at
```

messages table:

```
|id|sender_id|receiver_id|message|created_at|updated_at
```

User model:

```
public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Message::class, User::class,'id','sender_id');
}
```

i'm trying retrieve message threads
which isn't working. any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is thread here? Please describe it in details.

Comment: threads in the sense, list of users who sent messages to a user.

Comment: So, you want to get all users who have sent messages to a specific user (reciever) and you got the ID of that user?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from [laravel eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
    }
}
```

can you review your code

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to retrieve all messages that belongs to a single thread (list of users) using hasMany relationship Through `User` model, to do that You have to define `hasManyThrough` inside Thread model not in `User` model, here is an example:

User:

```
|id|name|email|password|created_at|updated_at|thread_id
```

Note `thread_id` foreign key because thread is a list of users

Thread:

```
class Thread extends Model {

    public function messages() {

        return $this->hasManyThrough(Message::class, User::class,'thread_id','sender_id', 'id', 'id');

    }

}
```

[Example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) from laravel doc